# Computed mesh has interspace on seams

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, mesh

I compute the mesh of a cube with vertices at **EXACTLY** the same positions but doubled, like this:

```
       +----+
      /    /
     /    /
Q0> +----+ <Q1
P0> +----+ <P1
    |    |
    |    |
    +----+
```

`P0` and `Q0` have excatly the same positions but are two distinct vertices. Same for `P1` and `Q1`.

What my shader needs is separate metadata at the vertices (`UV0`, `UV1`, color, whatever...). That's why I have to double the vertices despite being at the same location.

That said, my problem is as follows. On the seams along `P0->P1` and `Q0->Q1` an interspace is rendered. It's often less than a pixel but still perceptible. Look at this collage of renderings:

[image: Where the seams appear]

I've pointed the artifacts out with 4 blue arrows. The smaller image to the BL corner is a perfectly aligned camera while the bigger image is with an inclined camera.

I have no antialiasing (I need a pixelated art style) and textures are unfiltered with no mipmaps. If necessary I can give the full settings of textures.

My question is why do those artifacts appear on angled triangle seams? There are several more seams between triangles which are coplanar and no seams are ever visibile.

The UVs have a tiny padding above epsilon (1/100th of a pixel) to reduce texture bleeding. Textures are in an array, they are not in an atlas!

The algorithm is based on `int` and only on mesh construction uses `Vector3` and `float`. This means there cannot be any rounding error in the algorithm, which is very simple BTW.

The artifacts must originate post-conversion to the `Vector3` and look like rounding errors, but I expected from the hardware that exactly positioned vertices result in Peano-Jordan texels which perfectly align.

What is going on here and how can I remove those artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved now.

First, I set the texture to `Clamp` mode (it was `Repeat`). That solved the problem. But the mesh is generated procedurally in a way that `Repeat` is absolutely necessary.

So, I had to remove `Clamp` (and set it back to `Repeat`). But at that point it was clear what was going on: there is no interspace and everything is pixel-perfect. The problem lies in the texture padding, which was 1/100th of a pixel and thus way too low. I raised it to half of a pixel and the problem is gone!

I won't accept my own answer for ethical reasons, so this stays here just for posterity.